# BigQuery table url to read data in JSON format

Tags: android, json, url, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table which is connected to a microcontroller for storing sensor values. I intend to sync my BigQuery table via a URL to an Android app for reading sensor values. 
The hurdle I'm facing is that how to read the table via a URL to get the table data in JSON format.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Firebase is the solution to my question. Its so easy to deploy Firebase in your microcontroller program and android devices. It's a great IoT tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am recommending to build a middle ware, and then connect to it and grab the data from there.

Please note that BigQuery is a bigdata solution, and the fastest response time can be 1-2 seconds even for small queries, hence for your mobile app who doesn't display large dataset because simply mobiles cannot, it's best to connect o a middle ware and get data from even a different db engine and not BigQuery.

BigQuery API reference is here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Response time of 1-5 seconds is not a problem because in my app I'll be storing the data in Android DB and querying it via content provider-all in the background thread. All I'm looking for is a way to retrieve the BigQuery table data via some URL so that I can use it in my app.

Comment: added the link to the URL's documentation there you can pick the one you are interested, you probably need to use Jobs:insert() https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/insert

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand what do you want here. Do you want to see the latest sensor data in BigQuery or you want to see the whole table in BigQuery?

If it is the first, then you might want to run a query to filter out the latest results (through query jobs),

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data

We currently have no better way in getting just the last few rows out of the table easily and query might cost you money.

If it is the latter, then there is a tabledata.list api to allow you to retrieve the table. Comparing to running a query, it is free.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list

Comment: Yeah. I want to see the latest sensor data. Also, filtering by the latest timestamp via a query might do the job. But, the main hurdle is how to get the result in JSON format and also how to run the query via a url so that it can be queried from the android app.